# C++ Calling Functions from an Array of Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm using function pointers stored in an array with a typedef defining the pointer and I'm a little lost on how I'm supposed to call the function.

here's the Menu.h part:

```
typedef void( Menu::*FunctionPointer )();

FunctionPointer* m_funcPointers;
```

here's the Menu.cpp part:

```
Menu::Menu()
    : m_running( true )
    , m_frameChanged( true )
    , m_currentButton( 0 )
    , m_numOfButtons( k_maxButtons )
    , m_menuButtons( new MenuButton[k_maxButtons] )
    , m_nullBtn( new MenuButton( "null", Vector2( -1, -1 ) ) )
    , m_frameTimer( 0 )
    , m_funcPointers( new FunctionPointer[k_maxButtons])
{
    m_timer.start();
    clearButtons();
    mainMenu();
}

void Menu::enterButton()
{
    m_funcPointers[m_currentButton]();//Error here
}

void Menu::mainMenu()
{
    m_funcPointers[0] = &Menu::btnPlay;
    m_menuButtons[0] = MenuButton("Play", Vector2(0, 0));

    m_funcPointers[1] = &Menu::btnHiScores;
    m_menuButtons[1] = MenuButton("HiScores", Vector2(0, 1));

    m_funcPointers[2] = &Menu::btnExit;
    m_menuButtons[2] = MenuButton("Exit", Vector2(0, 2));
}
void Menu::btnPlay()
{
    StandardGame* game = new StandardGame();

    game->play();

    delete game;
}
```

m_currentButton is an integer used as the index. I'm not sure how to actually call the function as the above line gives me this error:

```
**C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments**
```

and visual studio give me this :

```
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

I don't know how to solve the above problem and whether it's due to how I'm calling the function or how I'm storing it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] first! Then, concerning your problem, please do some research up front, like e.g. using the error message in a websearch. If that doesn't turn up anything, extract a [mcve] please so people don't have to guess what the rest of the code looks like.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have done a fair bit of googling and can't figure out the problem but I can give more code if you want?

Comment: Please read the given link. You need to understand what MCVE means and then extract that from your code.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  Now the things are much clearer and the first answer is already there. A small improvement suggestion still:  could you indicate in the code snippet the line of the error message (ok, it's easy to guess, but it would allow quicker answer and avoid downvotes from upset readers ;-) ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Calling Functions from an Array of Function Pointers

You call a function pointer in an array the same way as you would call a function that is not in an array.

Your problem isn't how to call a function pointer in an array as such. Your problem that you're trying to call a member function pointer as if it were a function pointer.

You can call a member function pointer like this:

```
Menu menu; // you'll need an instance of the class
(menu.*m_funcPointers[m_currentButton])();
```

Edit for the new example code: Since you're in a member function, perhaps you intend to call the member function pointer on `this`:

```
(this->*m_funcPointers[m_currentButton])();
```

If you find the syntax painful to read, I won't blame you. Instead, I'll suggest using `std::invoke` instead (available since C++-17):

```
std::invoke(m_funcPointers[m_currentButton], this);
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, you edited just as I was about to ask whether I could use the this keyword.